# Extremely long time to establish network link with Nexus N9K-C9372-PX-E

Tags: cisco, 10gbase

This switch is completely default, no configuration has been done other than resetting it to default configuration, and going through the normal naming of the switch and time etc.

The problem I'm seeing is that it takes 30-45 seconds for clients to get fully linked/connected. So for example, if we restart one of our Ubuntu clients, the Ubuntu machine will get to the login screen and then it takes another good 30-40 seconds before we will get the notification saying "Connection established".

Comparing this to our other switches that generally have the connection ready within 3-5 seconds after hitting the login screen. Is there something specific to the switch that I can change to reduce the time it takes to establish a connection?

Comment: Not enough information.  Could it be spanning tree that causing your issue?

Comment: Logging in is host-specific which is off-topic here. You need to add details on when the link LED comes on (physical layer) and when data transfer starts (data link layer, check switch port status).

Comment: @RonTrunk As in configuring the switch for spanning tree? Or are you asking if I have loops in the network? If it is the latter, it does not have loops in the network. This is a diagram of the network. https://imgur.com/HpBrAnU

Comment: @Zac67 I'm not talking about logging in. I'm talking about how long it takes between when the connection is marked active and usable, I was using the login scenario as an example. In Ubuntu I can unplug the cable going to the 10Gb switch, plug it back in, and it takes 30-45 seconds before the connection is up and functioning (e.g. the little network connection wheel keeps spinning). If I plug the system up to one of our 1Gb switches it takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: The "little network connection wheel" is a host feature. Check out the switch LED/status instead.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a switch with a default configuration, spanning tree will block ports when they come up until the forwarding timer expires.

You can configure portfast on ports that have end hosts on them to allow spanning-tree to put the ports immediately into forwarding mode.

Comment: A true evergreen in networking: portfast trouble. Here probably in its NX-OS guise as "spanning tree port type edge" if the port is in access mode (single VLAN  untagged), respevtively as "spanning tree port type edge trunk" if the port is 802.1q with tagging towards the host. You wouldn't believe how many networks run without it, esepecially the without the latter variety...